# createsuperuser fails on postgresql only

Tags: django, postgresql

I am able to get my code and database to work just fine locally using sqlite3. But when I try and migrate to a postgresql platform, I get errors when I try to create the superuser, but not migrate or makemigration.

```
(trader) bubba@tuna:~/www/src/trader $ ./manage.py makemigrations                         
No changes detected
(trader) bubba@tuna:~/www/src/trader $ ./manage.py migrate        
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
(trader) bubba@tuna:~/www/src/trader $ ./manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'bubba'): 
Email address: bubba@trader.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 158, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 141, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 795, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/bubba/www/src/trader/accounts/signals.py", line 10, in customer_profile
    group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bubba/Env/trader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist.
```

These are my settings

```
$ cat trader/settings.py        
"""
Django settings for trader project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'boo'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.42.14']
ALLOWED_CIDR_NETS = ['192.168.42.0/24']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'django_filters',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'trader.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'trader.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'expungee',
        'USER':'boo',
        'PASSWORD':'boo',
        'HOST':'192.168.42.13',
        'PORT':'5432',
    }
}

#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/home/bubba/www/src/trader/db.sqlite3'),
#    }
#}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

I did try

```
django.db.backends.postgresql
```

but could not even connect.

```
exchangedb=# \du
                                     List of roles
   Role name   |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 administrator | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 expungee      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 expungeedb    |                                                            | {}
 postgres      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

How do I migrate to postgres?

UPDATED:

```
$ cat accounts/signals.py 
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


from .models import Customer

def customer_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
                group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
                instance.groups.add(group)
                Customer.objects.create(
                        user=instance,
                        name=instance.username,
                        )
                print('Profile created!')

post_save.connect(customer_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: You got a problem here: `  File "/home/bubba/www/src/trader/accounts/signals.py", line 10, in customer_profile
    group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')`  You should post your /home/bubba/www/src/trader/accounts/signals.py code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this line with a get or create call

```
group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='customer')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 manage.py migrate

python3 manage.py createsuperuser
```